# How to use scrollIntoView() for specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used scrollIntoView() method for scroll to the specific element.I have **two scrolls** in my **page**. One for **whole body** and another for one **specific div**. i have to scroll element only on that div. when i use scrollIntoView() first it will scroll whole body content then only that div scroll works. But i **need only that div scroll to specific element** in div. My code as following:

```
        $(".some-text").get(0).scrollIntoView(false);
```

**How to use it for specific div scroll???**

Comment: if you're already using jquery, why not use the jquery plugin scrollintoview()? which I think solves this issue built-in and makes the whole operation smoother --> https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview